# Read an integer list from single line input along with a range using list comprehension in Python 3

Tags: python, list-comprehension

**How to read an integer list from single line input along with a range in Python 3?**

**Requirement:** reading integer values for a given list separated by a space from single line input but with a range of given size.

example:

Range = 4

Then list size = 4

Then read the input list from a single line of size 4

I tried below list comprehension statement, but it is reading a list from 4 lines [i.e creating 4 lists with each list representing values from a given line] instead of reading only 1 list with a size of 4

```
    no_of_marks = 4
    marksList = [list(int(x) for x in input().split()) for i in range(no_of_marks)]
```

*Can someone help me in achieving my requirement?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.split` directly, passing the `no_of_marks` for being **maxsplit** parameter:

```
no_of_marks = 4
res = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ", no_of_marks)]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AgitatedHeartyApache)

Comment: Perfect, just like as I had expected. Thank you @Netwave!

Comment: @HarshaGV, glad to see it was helpful, please consider reading this so you can also collaborate: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, slice it to only take the first `n` words, and then turn them into integers.

```
marks = [int(x) for x in input().split()[:n]]
```

This will not fail if the input has fewer than `n` integers, so you should also check the length of the list

```
if len(marks) < n:
    raise ValueError("Not enough inputs")
```

Comment: this answer works as well.. can be used in case of list slices.. thank you @patrick-haugh